# force selected option in a select2 tag with options created via a JSON message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to push a value in my select box to be populated based on a value.  I am using a JSON query to build the select list, but it will not allow me to for a selected option.

Here is the HTML that is used to create the select list:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $("#u_product_name").select2(); });</script>    
<select id="u_product_name" name="u_product_name" style="width: 300px"></select>
```

Here is the code for the JSON request:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.getJSON('../prod_list_json/',function(data){
        document.getElementById('u_product_name').innerHTML = data;
    });
})
```

The list is populated correctly with all necessary option, but when I pass the data to select a specific option, it is still blank.

I have tried using this function top force the selected option to no avail:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#u_product_name").val($("#u_product_name_h").val());
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did more research and found adding line in my js provided the necessary change.
`$("#u_product_name").val($('#u_prod_id_h').val()).trigger("change");`

Answer (score 1):

Use this technique to set an option as selected:

```
selector option[value="opt_two"]').prop()
```

For example:

```
$('#u_product_name option[value="opt_two"]').prop('selected',true);
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/E22vm/)

**HTML:**

```
<select id="u_product_name" name="u_product_name" style="width: 300px"></select>
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="myButt" value="Populate Select" /> 
<input type="button" id="yrButt" value="Select option TWO" />
```

**js/jQuery:**

```
var added_by_getSON = '<option value="opt_one">one</option><option value="opt_two">two</option><option value="opt_three">three</option>';

$("#u_product_name").select2();

// Replaced with var "added_by_getJSON" to simulate AJAX...
//    $.getJSON('../prod_list_json/',function(data){
//        document.getElementById('u_product_name').innerHTML = data;
//    });
$('#myButt').click(function(){
    $('#u_product_name').append(added_by_getSON);
});
$('#yrButt').click(function(){
    $('#u_product_name option[value="opt_two"]').prop('selected',true);
    alert('Now look');
});
```

Comment: I tried the code you submitted, but it did not work.  I think this has an issue using the "select2" function as it is different from the standard HTML select tag.  If I remove that and use just the select tag, this works fine.  However, I lose the ability to directly type in, which is what I need to keep.

Comment: Just to add to that, with the select2, the value is set, and if I click the box, the option is highlighted, just not being presented in the box from the get go.